# Validating primitive types in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've implemented the following classes to validate data

```
public abstract class Validated
{
    public bool IsValid { get { return (GetRuleViolations().Count() == 0); } }

    public abstract IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations();
}

public partial class User: Validated
{
    public override IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
    {
        if (this.Age < 1)
            yield return new RuleViolation("Age can't be less than 1");
    }
}
```

It works great! When the form is submitted I just do

```
if (user.IsValid == false) blah...
```

But I still need to validate that the Age is an integer

```
int a = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(age, out a))
{
            error = "Not integer";
            // ...
}
```

How can I move this to my model?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Will have to do it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model binding in ASP.NET MVC does those kind of validation automatic (to be exact its being considere as model-binding errors). Please read very carefully through this: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html